# rails: redirect_to rendering but not reloading new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I would like my application to show a list of all associated objects when one is updated, so I would like to load the index action after an update is completed.

I have tried formatting the block, removing the format, render, and redirect_to. All of them just remain on the edit page

Update action:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @business_category.update_attributes(business_category_params)
        format.html {redirect_to admin_business_categories_path}
        return
      end
    end
  end
```

edit view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <%= link_to 'Back to categories', admin_business_categories_path %>
    </div><!-- .col -->
    <%= simple_form_for(@business_category, url: admin_business_category_path(@business_category), remote: true, html: { class: '' }) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'form', f: f %>
    <% end %>
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

_form partial:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Category Name' %>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button id="businessCategoryCancelButton" class="btn btn-warning">CANCEL</button>
    <%= f.submit 'SAVE', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

at the redirect_to a message appears in the console:

```
No template found for Admin::BusinessCategoriesController#update, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 1505ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

I don't know why it is looking for the update template or why it is not redirecting to the index action

I am trying to understand how format works and if/why it would be conflicting with the redirect. Any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are issuing an AJAX call (`remote: true` on your form).

You have the following options:

- Add `format.js` to the controller
- Remove `remote: true` from the form definition and the `respond_to` from the controller:

```rb
def update
  if @business_category.update_attributes(business_category_params)
    redirect_to admin_business_categories_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`simple_form_for(@business_category, url: admin_business_category_path(@business_category), remote: true, html: { class: '' })`

In your form you've mentioned `remote: true`. It process your request as a `JS` request. In your controller you've mentioned `format.html {redirect_to admin_business_categories_path}` but it will process it as `format.js` and look for `update.js.erb` file to handle the response because your format of request is 'JS' instead of 'HTML', hence it's showing an error.

You'll have to send the request as an HTML request.

According to your implementation. I think you just want to redirect in case of success and render edit page again in case of error.

You'll have to make 2 changes.

1. Remove remote: true from form as it doesn't match your requirement
2. Add the line `format.html { render :edit }` in else case of `update_attributes()`